# Split numbered equation over multiple pages

Tags: equations, align

I am writing long equations and each equation has to jump to a new page. I'm using

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
............
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

I've looked , but the only way I found , is using `\begin{align*}` and tagged it with
`\tag{\stepcounter{equation}\theequation}` but when I try to label it , I get an error:

> `Missing \endcsname inserted`. `\end{align*}`

Without label works just fine.

Comment: Why not just use `align`?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#align_and_align.2A) - you might want to use the `align` environment and just suppress numbers with `\nonumber` on those lines you need no number.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `split` environment is meant to be used inside another environment, say, an`equation` environment. The `split` environment does *not* provide its own numbering and labeling support; instead, it is assumed that the "outer" environment (in your case: `equation`) handles those chores. You appear to have "discovered" a way to get around this constraint through the use of nested `\tag` and `\stepcounter{equation}` instructions, but you've also discovered that the cross-referencing mechanism using `\label` directives doesn't work.

The `align*` environment, by the way, is designed not to produce equation numbers, and that's why you have to resort to the same work-around as for `split` environments.

Rather than devise an additional, and likely kludgy, fix to solve the cross-referencing problem (which might involve using `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`, but you didn't learn this from me...), you should consider dropping the use of `align*` or nested `equation`/`split` environments and, instead, consider using `align` environments. Within an `align` environment, use `\notag` (or `\nonumber`)in those rows that should no get an equation number, and use `\label` instructions for the numbered lines you wish to be able to cross-reference using `\ref` and friends.